# Are Vec can be reduced in Chisel?

Tags: scala, chisel

I'm trying to reduce a `Vec` of Bundle in an `UInt`, but got an error:

```scala
class DiffPair extends Bundle {
    val p = Bool()
    val n = Bool()
}

class TMDS extends Bundle {
    val clk  = new DiffPair()
    val data = Vec(3, new DiffPair())
}
val io = IO(new Bundle {
 //...
 val tmds = Output(new TMDS())
})

val O_tmds_data_p = IO(Output(UInt(3.W)))
```

If I use this `reduce` code :

```scala
O_tmds_data_p := gbHdmi.io.tmds.data.reduce((a,b) => Cat(a.p, b.p))
```

I've got this error :

```
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to /home/user/GbHdmi/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /home/user/GbHdmi/src/main/scala/topgbhdmi.scala:72:67: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.UInt
[error]  required: gbhdmi.DiffPair
[error]       O_tmds_data_p := gbHdmi.io.tmds.data.reduce((a,b) => Cat(a.p, b.p))
[error]                                                                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 31 août 2021, 15:04:08
```

I know that `a` and `b` are `DiffPair`, but `a.p` and `b.p` are `Bool` no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to take 'p' value with `map` before reduce :

```scala
O_tmds_data_p := gbHdmi.io.tmds.data.map(_.p.asUInt).reduce((a,b) => Cat(a,b))
```

Or, in simplified way :

```scala
O_tmds_data_p := gbHdmi.io.tmds.data.map(_.p.asUInt).reduce(_ ## _)
```

And, that way didn't work, for an obscur reason to me :

```scala
O_tmds_data_p := gbHdmi.io.tmds.data.reduce(_.p.asUInt ## _.p.asUInt)
```

Error :

```
sbt:GbHdmi> runMain gbhdmi.TopGbHdmiDriver
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to /home/user/GbHdmi/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /home/user/GbHdmi/src/main/scala/topgbhdmi.scala:71:63: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.UInt
[error]  required: gbhdmi.DiffPair
[error]       O_tmds_data_p :=  gbHdmi.io.tmds.data.reduce(_.p.asUInt ## _.p.asUInt)
[error]                                                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 1, 2021, 9:17:15 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
O_tmds_data_p := gbHdmi.io.tmds.data.asUInt
```

I think that should work for you.

Comment: I will have problem because data is a DiffPair of n and p no ?

Comment: Take a look at https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3IUJxnJWQf6Uamq8i9mrkA I think that shows it working

Comment: Yes, but I need to take only the p from the DiffPair.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, but it looks like you found the write approach, something like   out := VecInit(x.map(_.p)).asUInt